# Event Source return data length

Tags: php, server-sent-events

This article

[enter link description here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

provides an excellent introduction to Server Sent Events.  The one thing that is not clear to me is this - they have a section entitled Multiline Data where they say "If your message is longer...".  Longer than what?  The statement seems to imply that long messages should be broken up into multiple data:value\n strings.  If so, longer than what threshold length?

All I want to do is to send back a JSON string which I then process client side.  The string contains, amongst other things HTML markup so it could get quite long - between 4 and 8 Kb would be typical. I should mention that my server side code is PHP.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... No answers.  I cannot say that I have found a definitive answer either but for the benefit of anyone running into this thread.  Purely an empirical observation - there is no need to break up data into multiple lines just becuase there is a lot of it.  In my own tests I have had no issues with data strings of up to 2048 characters.  Given that I am unlikely to exceed that limit, the issue is solved AFAIC.  A definitive answer from somone in the know would still be nice though.